# How to store a result to a variable in HP OpenVMS DCL?

Tags: openvms, dcl

I want to save the output of a program to a variable.

I use the following approach ,but fail.

`$ PIPE RUN TEST | DEFINE/JOB VALUE @SYS$PIPE
$ x = f$logical("VALUE")`

I got an error:`%DCL-W-MAXPARM, too many parameters - reenter command with fewer parameters
 \WORLD\`

reference :
[How to assign the output of a program to a variable in a DCL com script on VMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4431757/how-to-assign-the-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable-in-a-dcl-com-script-on-vms)

Comment: I'm guessing that the output of the program is more than a single token, i.e. something like "Hello world.". You need to quote the value to get it into a logical name. Not sure of the precise syntax, but probably some variation on `DEFINE/JOB VALUE "''@SYS$PIPE'"`.

Comment: `"''@SYS$PIPE'"` will not work: single quoting is for DCL symbols, only. `SYS$PIPE` is a logical and `@` is input redirection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to write the output to a file and read from the file and put that into a DCL symbol (or logical). Although not obvious, you can do this with the PIPE command was well:

```
$ pipe r 2words
hello world
$ pipe r 2words |(read sys$pipe line ; line=""""+line+"""" ; def/job value &line )
$ sh log value
   "VALUE" = "hello world" (LNM$JOB_85AB4440)
$
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you are able to change the program, add some code to it to write the required values into symbols or logicals (see LIB$ routines)

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the program, using LIB$SET_SYMBOL in the program defines a DCL symbol (what you are calling a variable) for DCL. That's the cleanest way to do this. If it really needs to be a logical, then there are system calls that define logicals.