# How to enable case sensitive in HP openVMS DCL?

Tags: openvms, dcl

My DCL as below  (TEST.EXE just print the input )

```
$ DEFINE DCL$PATH SYS$DISK:[],SYS$LOGIN:,SYS$SYSTEM:
$ PIPE TEST.EXE abc | DEFINE/JOB RET_VALUE @SYS$PIPE
$ x = f$logical("RET_VALUE")
$ WRITE SYS$OUTPUT x
```

I want to let this DCL show the result is "abc". 
But this DCL result will show "ABC".

I try add "SET PROCESS/CASE_LOOKUP=SENSITIVE" in DCL, but not workable.

Does anyone have any suggestion or tips? Thanks a lot.

Comment: IMHO `$ DEFINE DCL$PATH SYS$DISK:[],SYS$LOGIN:,SYS$SYSTEM:` is a bad idea, suppose a typo like `*sh lo abc` that will lead to launch in sys$system, the file opccrash.exe, so you will reboot very quickly...

Comment: Depends on your privileges and the definition of the logical `OPC$REBOOT` :-)  But yes, you can shoot yourself in the foot - as you can do on Unix/bash if you provide a pathname with wildcards. I don't want to argue, the basic idea with this definition is to avoid the `MCR` command or to define foreign commands for all the utilities in `SYS$SYSTEM`. That can be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check whether the accepted answer in  [How to store a result to a variable in HP OpenVMS DCL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890693/how-to-store-a-result-to-a-variable-in-hp-openvms-dcl) helps with this question?

Your DEFINE command in the pipe is `DEFINE/JOB RET_VALUE abc`, which by DCL is changed to  `DEFINE/JOB RET_VALUE ABC`. DCL doesn't change to UPPERCASE, when the equivalence-name is quoted, which would be a `DEFINE/JOB RET_VALUE "abc"`. However, when you write `"@SYS$PIPE"`, you have the string `@SYS$PIPE` as equivalence-name. In other words, within a string the redirector `@` no longer works. So you have to get the string from `SYS$PIPE` as is, for example with a `READ`, as illustrated in the linked answer.

PS: ... and you probably want the remove the `.exe` from `test.exe` in your pipe command.